# Сортировка данных пользователей

Tags: java

Есть персональные данные пользователей, которые мы получаем в формате:

```
Name: Alex  
Surname: Ivanov  
Age: 35  
City: Moscow
```

и т.д.

Необходимо поменять поля этих данных местами, некоторые вообще выкинуть, но нет возможности поменять изначальные поля, в которые пользователь вводит данные. Т.е. нужно чтобы результатом работы программы стал вывод:

```
Surname: Ivanov  
Name: Alex  
City: Moscow
```

Данные поступают в виде файла с массивом строк, на выходе тоже нужен массив строк. В идеале реализовать это как простое приложение, в которое загружают файл и нажатием кнопки "Сортировать" получается вывод в консоль уже отсортированного списка с нужным порядком строк, либо выгрузку в файл, но это не суть, тут сам разберусь, надеюсь. Вопрос больше по сортировке.

Подскажите каким способом это можно реализовать?
Может есть возможность создать некий шаблон, в который программа будет помещать полученную информацию в нужном нам порядке?
Или данные каждого пользователя помещать в массив, в котором строки будут пронумерованы в нужном нам порядке а потом уже сортировать по возрастанию?

Comment: откуда поступают данные? с консоли? с файла? еще откуда-то? в каком виде поступают? Как массив Стрингов? Один Стринг? В каком виде нужны данные на выходе? в виде массива классов? стрингов? Нужно больше информации

Comment: Ну сразу приходит на ум распарсить получаемую строку. И на каждого человека создавать объект класса Человек. Пример добавил в ответы: (если я правильно понял задачу)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Test9 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
 String text = "Name: Alex Surname: Ivanov Age: 35 City: Moscow\n" +
         "Name: Ivan Surname: Petrov Age: 31 City: New-York\n" +
         "Name: Tatuyana Surname: Fedorova Age: 18 City: Madrid\n" +
         "Name: Fedor Surname: Denisov Age: 44 City: London\n";
        List<Person>people=getList(text); //получаем список людей
        print(people); //выводим на экран нужные поля людей и отсортированные согласно компоратору в методе
        // можно в параметры метода принт передать поля, которые нужно выводить на экран



    }

    public static List<Person> getList(String text){
        //Парсим все строки и превращаем их в людей, и добавляем в Лист
        //В зависимости от формата входных данных парсить можно по-разному:
        //регулярные выражения, методы Стринга - сплит, сабстринг и т.д.
        List<Person>people = new ArrayList<>();
        String [] array = text.split("\n");

        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
        {
            String [] inAr = array[i].split(" ");
            people.add(new Person(inAr[1],inAr[3],Integer.valueOf(inAr[5]),inAr[7]));
        }
        return people;
    }

    public static void print(List<Person> people){
        // в этом методе выбираем уже какие поля выводить, какие не выводить. По какому полю
        // отсортировать людей и т.д. выходные данные в зависимости от цели, можете вернуть строкой,
        // записать в файл и т.д.

        //создаем Компоратор - по которому будем сортировать людей, у меня это будет возраст:
        //при необходимости можно создать различные компораторы и передавать в метод тот, который необходим:
        Comparator<Person> comparator= (o1, o2) -> o1.age-o2.age;
        people.sort(comparator); //сортируем людей по компоратору выше

        //Вывод на экран нужных полей:
        for(Person person: people){
            System.out.println("Surname: "+person.surname);
            System.out.println("Name: "+person.name);
            System.out.println("Age: " + person.age);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}

class Person{
    String name;
    String surname;
    int age;
    String city;

    public Person(String name, String surname, int age, String city) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.age = age;
        this.city = city;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", surname='" + surname + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                ", city='" + city + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Выход:

```
Surname: Fedorova
Name: Tatuyana
Age: 18

Surname: Petrov
Name: Ivan
Age: 31

Surname: Ivanov
Name: Alex
Age: 35

Surname: Denisov
Name: Fedor
Age: 44


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Дальше нужно подганять код под задачи. Если нужен именно массив стрингов, то вместо вывода на печать на каждого человека нужно создавать объект стрингбилдер и конкатенировать нужные строки и добавлять в массив, который в итоге вернуть из метода